# How to attach a text box to an mouse cursor in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have a data curve displayed in a matplotlib figure. I would like to attach a text box to the mouse cursor. That is, as the mouse cursor is moved around in the figure, the text box is moved with it. Also, I would like to be able to update the text in the text box as the cursor with attached text box is moved.

I started with the matplotlib example at https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/cursor_demo_sgskip.html but was unsuccessful in modification of it for my purpose. I also looked at some 3rd party packages (e.g. mpldatacursor and mplcursors); but, these did not seem appropriate for my application.

Here is some code that I was experimenting with that should illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-#
#!/usr/bin/env python
# The following allows special characters to be in comments (e.g. the extended Swedish alphabet)
# coding:utf-8
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# For setting size and position of matplotlib figure 
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("WXAgg")
import numpy as np

class Cursor(object):
    """
     Purpose: Define a cursor whose interesection will track points along a curve
    """
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.ax = ax
        self.lx = ax.axhline(color='k',linewidth=0.25)  # the horiz line
        self.ly = ax.axvline(color='k',linewidth=0.25)  # the vert line

        # Text location in axes coords
        self.txt = ax.text(0.7, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

    def mouse_move(self, event):
        '''
         Purpose: respond to movement of the mouse
        '''
        if not event.inaxes: return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.4)
        self.ax.text(x, y, 'test',  fontsize=8, bbox=props) 
        #self.ax.text(x,y,'')   
        #self.text(x, y, 'test',  fontsize=8, bbox=props)   
        #ax.text(x, y, 'test',  fontsize=8, bbox=props)   
        # Update the line positions
        self.lx.set_ydata(y)
        self.ly.set_xdata(x)

        self.txt.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        self.ax.text(x,y,'')   
        plt.draw()

class SnaptoCursor(object):
    """
    Like Cursor but the current center of the crosshair at (x,y) will snap to the nearest
    (x,y) on the curve.
    For simplicity, I'm assuming x is sorted
    """
    def __init__(self, ax, x, y):
        self.ax  = ax
        self.lx  = ax.axhline(color='k')  # the horiz line
        self.ly  = ax.axvline(color='k')  # the vert line
        self.x   = x
        self.y   = y
        # Text location in axes coords

        self.txt = ax.text(0.7, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)


    def mouse_move(self, event):
        """
         Purpose: Track the movement of the mouse coords and then update the position
                  of the intersection of the cursor cross-hairs
        """
        if not event.inaxes:            
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata       # x,y coordinates of mouse

        props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.4)
        self.ax.text(x, y, 'test',  fontsize=8, bbox=props)            
        #self.text(x, y, 'test',  fontsize=8, bbox=props)   
        #ax.text(x, y, 'test',  fontsize=8, bbox=props)           
        #self.ax.text(remove)   

        # Find closest pt on data curve to (x,y) of cross-air intersection
        indx = min(np.searchsorted(self.x, [x])[0], len(self.x) - 1)
        x = self.x[indx]
        y = self.y[indx]
        # Update the line positions
        self.lx.set_ydata(y)
        self.ly.set_xdata(x)
        # place a text box in upper left in axes coords
        #self.ax.text(x, y, 'test', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=8,
        #        verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)        

        self.txt.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        print('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        plt.draw()

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,7.5))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('TS with tracking cursor')
# Need the following to set position the plot
pltManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
pltManager.window.SetPosition((20,20))  # pixels offset from top left corner of display   

# cursor = Cursor(ax)
cursor = SnaptoCursor(ax, t, s)
plt.connect('motion_notify_event', cursor.mouse_move)

ax.plot (t, s, 'o')   

plt.axis([0, 1, -1, 1])
plt.grid(axis='both')
plt.show()
```

The text box does "stick" with the mouse cursor but it is not erased when the cursor is moved --- this is what needs to be solved. One small step in the right direction

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-#
#!/usr/bin/env python
# The following allows special characters to be in comments (e.g. the extended Swedish alphabet)
# coding:utf-8
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# For setting size and position of matplotlib figure 
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("WXAgg")
import numpy as np


class SnaptoCursor(object):
    """
    Like Cursor but the current center of the crosshair at (x,y) will snap to the nearest
    (x,y) on the curve.
    For simplicity, I'm assuming x is sorted
    """
    def __init__(self, ax, x, y):
        self.ax  = ax
        self.lx  = ax.axhline(color='k')  # the horiz line
        self.ly  = ax.axvline(color='k')  # the vert line

        self.tx  = ax.text(0.0,0.0,'test')        # the text to follow cursor

        self.x   = x
        self.y   = y
        # Text location in axes coords
        self.txt = ax.text(0.7, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)


    def mouse_move(self, event):
        """
         Purpose: Track the movement of the mouse coords and then update the position
                  of the intersection of the cursor cross-hairs
        """
        if not event.inaxes:            
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata       # x,y coordinates of mouse
        self.tx.set_position((x,y))

        # Find closest pt on data curve to (x,y) of cross-air intersection
        indx = min(np.searchsorted(self.x, [x])[0], len(self.x) - 1)
        x = self.x[indx]
        y = self.y[indx]
        # Update the line positions
        self.lx.set_ydata(y)
        self.ly.set_xdata(x)

        self.txt.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        print('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        plt.draw()

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,7.5))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('TS with tracking cursor')
# Need the following to set position the plot
pltManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
pltManager.window.SetPosition((20,20))  # pixels offset from top left corner of display   

cursor = SnaptoCursor(ax, t, s)
plt.connect('motion_notify_event', cursor.mouse_move)

ax.plot (t, s, 'o')   

plt.axis([0, 1, -1, 1])
plt.grid(axis='both')
plt.show()
```

This code will move the text with the cursor and erase previous text. However, I am still unable to change the text as the cursor is moved! Any suggestions would be appreciated :-)

Comment: It sounds like you want something [like this](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/hover.html#sphx-glr-examples-hover-py) and perhaps *have already tried it*, but failed. In order to get some help here, you should edit your question to provide some code example and description of *what went wrong*.

Comment: No Shanteshwar, this code does not attach text to the cursor; but, instead shows text when the cursor is near a point. But, thanks for looking at it. I have attached some code which I was working with and hopefully shows the problem that I am having. Perhaps, I need to know more about "blitting"

Answer (score 1):

You were creating a new `Text` object everytime you moved the mouse. You need to create the object during `__init__` and then simply update its position/text when the mouse is moved:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-#
#!/usr/bin/env python
# The following allows special characters to be in comments (e.g. the extended Swedish alphabet)
# coding:utf-8
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# For setting size and position of matplotlib figure 
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("WXAgg")
import numpy as np

class Cursor(object):
    """
     Purpose: Define a cursor whose interesection will track points along a curve
    """
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.ax = ax
        self.lx = ax.axhline(color='k',linewidth=0.25)  # the horiz line
        self.ly = ax.axvline(color='k',linewidth=0.25)  # the vert line

        # Text location in data coords
        props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.4)
        self.txt = self.ax.text(0, 0, '', fontsize=8, bbox=props)

    def mouse_move(self, event):
        '''
         Purpose: respond to movement of the mouse
        '''
        if not event.inaxes: return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        self.txt.set_position((x,y))
        # Update the line positions
        self.lx.set_ydata(y)
        self.ly.set_xdata(x)

        self.txt.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        plt.draw()

class SnaptoCursor(object):
    """
    Like Cursor but the current center of the crosshair at (x,y) will snap to the nearest
    (x,y) on the curve.
    For simplicity, I'm assuming x is sorted
    """
    def __init__(self, ax, x, y):
        self.ax  = ax
        self.lx  = ax.axhline(color='k')  # the horiz line
        self.ly  = ax.axvline(color='k')  # the vert line
        self.x   = x
        self.y   = y

        # Text location in data coords
        props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.4)
        self.txt = self.ax.text(0, 0, '', fontsize=8, bbox=props)


    def mouse_move(self, event):
        """
         Purpose: Track the movement of the mouse coords and then update the position
                  of the intersection of the cursor cross-hairs
        """
        if not event.inaxes:            
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata       # x,y coordinates of mouse

        self.txt.set_position((x,y))

        # Find closest pt on data curve to (x,y) of cross-air intersection
        indx = min(np.searchsorted(self.x, [x])[0], len(self.x) - 1)
        x = self.x[indx]
        y = self.y[indx]
        # Update the line positions
        self.lx.set_ydata(y)
        self.ly.set_xdata(x)
        # place a text box in upper left in axes coords
        #self.ax.text(x, y, 'test', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=8,
        #        verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)        

        self.txt.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        print('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,7.5))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('TS with tracking cursor')

# cursor = Cursor(ax)
cursor = SnaptoCursor(ax, t, s)
plt.connect('motion_notify_event', cursor.mouse_move)

ax.plot (t, s, 'o')   

plt.axis([0, 1, -1, 1])
plt.grid(axis='both')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Very good DA! -- Thanks. One more add-on. How could the cross-hairs and text be blitted to prevent the flickering (at least on my system)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly edited version of Diziet Asahithat's code that answers my question:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-#
#!/usr/bin/env python
# The following allows special characters to be in comments (e.g. the extended Swedish alphabet)
# coding:utf-8
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# For setting size and position of matplotlib figure 
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("WXAgg")
import numpy as np

class SnaptoCursor(object):
    """
    Like normal cursor but the current center of the crosshair at (x,y) will snap to the nearest
    (x,y) on the curve.
    For simplicity, I'm assuming x is sorted
    """
    def __init__(self, ax, x, y):
        self.ax  = ax
        self.lx  = ax.axhline(color='k')  # the horiz line
        self.ly  = ax.axvline(color='k')  # the vert line
        self.x   = x
        self.y   = y
        # Text location in data coords (this is required!)
        props    = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.4)
        self.txt = self.ax.text(0, 0, '', fontsize=8, bbox=props)

    def mouse_move(self, event):
        """
         Purpose: Track the movement of the mouse coords and then update the position
                  of the intersection of the cursor cross-hairs along with the text box
        """
        if not event.inaxes:            
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata       # x,y coordinates of mouse
        # Update the position of the text in the box attached to the cursor
        self.txt.set_position((x+0.02,y))     # place the text in the box

        # Place the center of the cross-hairs
        indx = min(np.searchsorted(self.x, [x])[0], len(self.x) - 1)
        x = self.x[indx]
        y = self.y[indx]
        # Update the line positions
        self.lx.set_ydata(y)
        self.ly.set_xdata(x)

        # Place text in the text box
        self.txt.set_text('Test\n x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        #print('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14.5,7.2))
ax.set_ylim(-1,+1)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('TS with tracking cursor')
# Need the following to set position the plot
pltManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
pltManager.window.SetPosition((20,20))  # pixels offset from top left corner of display   


cursor = SnaptoCursor(ax, t, s)
plt.connect('motion_notify_event', cursor.mouse_move)

ax.plot (t, s, 'o')   

plt.axis([0, 1, -1, 1])
plt.grid(axis='both')
plt.show()
```

Thanks very much for your efforts DA :-)